# UPS Rates API - International shipping

Tags: rate, shipping-method, ups

I have an implementation for shipping working for US shipping, however I am unable to get this implementation to work with international shipping. I am using the shipping codes 07, 08, 54, and 55 but am getting the error

> "111210 The requested service is unavailable between the selected locations.".

I dont get this error when I enter a ship to address in the US. I have tried Spain and Mexico.

Does the rates API support international shipping? Is there anything different that needs to be done or passed in to get international shipping rates to work?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: nope sorry. I ended up convincing the client that intl shipping would be too much of a pain.

Answer (score 8):

After posting my comment to OP I found the solution I was looking for. In case anyone else encounters this post while researching this problem here's what worked for me:

In your request, for Service Code, use one of the Worldwide codes. I used 65 (UPS Worldwide Saver) for my specific needs.

Hope that helps someone in the future!

Comment: Thanks for this.  The UPS documentation is clear as mud about what the different Service Codes actually mean.

Comment: WOW. You just saved my ass. I thank God for you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in the UPS sample code for PHP, the "SimpleRate" array BREAKS the international shipping rate queries, it errors out with a the message "The requested accessory option is unavailable between the selected locations."

It is embarrassing how long this took me to figure out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).